# Plotting graph and fft in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I have data of one column and for arround 200 rows.(1 D array). But these data is been taken for around 1 min of time.
So I need plot this  data vs time graph(data vs total time of one minute) and also need to perform FFT  also.
Any possible methods?????

Comment: What methods have you already tried? Providing code is pretty necessary around here.

Comment: You can find several methods for calculating fft in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html

Comment: I realy don't have any Ideas to do this any  Ideas!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Also I need to know how to plot data against total time of 1 minute .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets imagine we have a data set called (x,y) and we wanna fit a curve like y=a*sin(b*x+c)
in order to fit, you need something like this

```
 from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

    def func(a,b,c,x):
"""We define the kind of function we want to fit"""  
        return a*np.sin(b*x+c)  

result = curve_fit(func, x, y) #func uses the function defined before, x and y are data points.
result[0] #array of the values
result[1] #covariance matrix
```

And then, if yo want to plot it with matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

plt.plot(x,result[0]*np.sin(result[1]*x+result[2]), 'g--')
```

Comment: the first argument in func() are the x-values